# Argparse with two values for one argument

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

Now my script calls via:

```
python resylter.py -n *newfile* -o *oldfile*
```

code looks like:

```
parser.add_argument('-n', '--newfile', help='Uses only with -o argument. Compares inputed OLD (-o) file with previous run results with NEW(-n) output.xml file with actual run results')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--oldfile', help='Uses only with -n argument. Compares inputed OLD (-o)  file with previous run results with NEW(-n) output.xml file with actual run results')
```

and some actions

How i can edit it to use like this?:

```
python resylter.py -n *newfile* *oldfile*
```

sys.argv[-1] didn't works

Comment: I don't think if this would be useful. I'd just leave `oldfile` as [positional argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#name-or-flags) (i.e. `parser.add_argument('oldfile', ...)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wokrs with `nargs = '*'`

I did following:

```
parser.add_argument('-c', '--compare', nargs = '*')

_newfile_ = _args_.compare[0]
_oldfile_ = _args_.compare[1]
```

and it works now

Comment: The star in `nargs='*'` means zero or more arguments (like in regex), which doesn't make sense in this context.

Answer (score 39):

Use [`nargs=2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs):

```
parser.add_argument(
    '-c',
    '--compare',
    nargs=2,
    metavar=('newfile', 'oldfile'),
    help='Compares previous run results in oldfile with current run results in newfile.',
    )

args = parser.parse_args()

newfile, oldfile = args.compare
```

Also adding [`metavar=('newfile', 'oldfile')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar) improves the help text if you run `resylter.py -h`.

Comment: For completeness, I am adding that the type of each value can be set by, for example, `type=float` and the default can be set using a list, e.g. `default=[0.5, 0.2]`